# Query both UserStory and Defects at same time for WsapiDataStore

Tags: rally

Is there a way to query multiple 'models' using a single query?  Similar to lookback query using _Type: {'$in': ['HierarchicalRequirement','Defect']}

```
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    model: ['UserStory','Defect'], //this does NOT work
                    context: context,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    filters: newFilter,
                    fetch: 'Name,FormattedID,AcceptedDate,ScheduleState,PlanEstimate,KanbanState',
                sorters: [
                          {
                              property: 'AcceptedDate',
                              direction: 'ASC'
                          }
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                    load: this._onDataLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the RUI SDK, but hopefully will be sometime down the road.